# Instagram Selenium Login Java not Working

Tags: java, selenium, android-studio, selenium-webdriver, instagram

So I started a new Project with Selenium in Android Studio with Java and it seems like that I have run into a problem. What I am trying to do is to open instagram then to click on the only essential cookies , to fill out the name and password until then it works perfectly but after that it won't press the login button no matter what I try it will just stop
So this is my code (I changed my Username and Password of course):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver","/usr/bin/safaridriver");
        SafariDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en&source=auth_switcher");

        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.findElement(By.className("HoLwm")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xyzzy");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xyzzy");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("\"//button[@type='submit']\"")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("\"//button[@type='submit']\"")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        }
```

and somehow I get an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: "//button[@type='submit']" (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'

 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: Safari, browserVersion: 15.4, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, safari:automaticInspection: false, safari:automaticProfiling: false, safari:diagnose: false, safari:platformBuildVersion: 20G527, safari:platformVersion: 11.6.5, safari:useSimulator: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, webkit:WebRTC: {DisableICECandidateFiltering: false, DisableInsecureMediaCapture: false}}
Session ID: D249B2A9-5C9F-4000-A778-8D9B4D81A240
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:87)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:231)
 at com.example.instagramrepost.MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:39)
```

can someone pls help me thank you

Comment: The error is with the line containing `xpath: //div[text()='Log In']` which I don't see in your code block.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Sorry was the wrong error code. The right one is now in the Question

Comment: Check if button can actually be found with this xpath.

Comment: @shomeax Thanks , It still doesn't work so I tried it with the cssSelector : "\"#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button > div\"" and it seems like that there is some invalid selector exception why it can't find the button do you see something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

This code works 100% of the time
But still thanks to those who tried to help me with the issue

Answer (score 0):

Would be very helpful if you'd added example of login page html code, you may use Web Inspector (Safari) or Web Developer (Chrome) to capture page code.

But guessing out of the wild, it seems that you have extra `\"` in your xpath, possibly due to copy-pasting.

Try `By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")` instead of `By.xpath("\"//button[@type='submit']\"")`, it should find your button.

Comment: Ok so this fixed my problem `Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']"));
        act.doubleClick(ele).perform();
        ele.click();`    But now I have the problem that is is really inconsistent with pressing it or not sometimes it will press it 5 times in a row and then 10 times again not it is so weird and I have no solution for it

Comment: :)
That's exactly what `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(...))` is for. Update selector there as well and it should fix your inconcistencies